# Primary Key, Foreign Key for Entity Framework class

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-4.1

For this class:

```
 public class Movie   {
 public int MovieId { get; set; }
 public string Title { get; set; }
 public int Rating { get; set; }
 public int ProducerID { get; set; }
 public Producer Producer { get; set; }
     }
```

I just want to know which one will be used as the primary key when Entity Framework maps this class to the corresponding database table?

also which one would be the foreign key?

Comment: You need to define primary key, foreign key using data annotations otherwise it'll be just a table without keys

Comment: Movie Id will be a primary key

Primary Key >> Property named Id , or property named ClassName+Id like MovieId or property which has [Key] attribute.
You can also use ef 6 conventions or you can use ef fulent mapping and entity configurations

There is no foreign key here.